# IntelliJ django unittests 'Apps aren't loaded'

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I have a few unittests in my project, these can be run by `python manage.py test` which works fine.

Now I want to test some test-cases alone with the IntelliJ built-in tester (where each test a this little green triangle).

If I run a specific test through IntelliJ I get:

```
File "/Users/user1/ProgProjects/active/law-orga/backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Process finished with exit code 1

Empty suite

Empty suite
```

My environment variables contain `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1;DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=backend.settings;` (backend is the name of the app).

I tried to add `django.setup()` to my settings.py file, then the tests work **but** they use the local database, not a dedicated test database which gets built and destroyed every time. Additionally the teardown still works, so my local database just gets whipped at the end.

I use the most recent version of IntelliJ Ultimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got it working.

There were two problems:

1. apparently you need the right Facet, so IntelliJ Ultimate recognizes that its a django module
2. if you create a new project with IntelliJ, I guess it defaults to a Java project, so Facets like 'django' don't get recognized or are invalid

Now the solution:

- Edit the `project.iml`-file in the `.idea` folder in the root of the project. Change the second line from something like `<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">` to `<module type="PYTHON_MODULE" version="4">`. Restart your IDE.
- I guess it's possible that, if you already have the correct Facets, its working now. If not, add the right Facet through: File - Project Structure - Facets. Just add a new one with django and fill in your settings.

However if there is an error in adding the Facet, you can add in manually. Get to the project.iml file again and insert this code. But keep the xml-structure intact.

```
<facet type="django" name="Django">
    <configuration>
        <option name="rootFolder" value="$MODULE_DIR$/backend" />
        <option name="settingsModule" value="backend/settings.py" />
        <option name="manageScript" value="manage.py" />
        <option name="environment" value="&lt;map/&gt;" />
        <option name="doNotUseTestRunner" value="false" />
        <option name="trackFilePattern" value="" />
    </configuration>
</facet>
```

These are my settings for an app with the name `backend`, edit these according to your own project.

The xml-structure should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="PYTHON_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="Python" name="Python">
      ...
    </facet>
    <facet type="django" name="Django">
      ... (facet from above for example)
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component>
    ...
  </component>
</module>
```

I hope this helps anyone.